# Cannot unpack non-iterable object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a basic doubt about the following;

```
D = [{'one':1,'two':'Hello','three':3},{'four':4,'five':'World!','six':6}]
for a,b,c in list(D[0].values()):
    print(a,b,c)
```

It gives the following error;

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

I know there are certain solutions related to the similar problem but I am still not able to resolve the problem. Please help me resolve this problem. Thank You.

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to achieve? `list(D[0].values())` is a list of `[1, 'Hello', 3]` and then you iterate over it. If you want to unpack it, you simply do: `a, b, c = D[0].values()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that `list(D[0].values())` is already a list, so you want **either** a for loop **or** an expansion assignment, not both together:

```
a, b, c = list(D[0].values())
print(a, b, c)
```